# Error during install of neo4j as service

Tags: java, neo4j, installation

I've run `bin\neo4j install-service` and I've received following error:

> Invoke-Neo4j : Unable to determine the path to java.exe
>   At line:1 char:281
>
> - try { Unblock-File -Path 'E:\Soft 3\neo4j-community-3.3.5-windows\neo4j-community-3.3.5\bin\Neo4j-Management*.*' -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue' } catch {}
>     ;Import-Module 'E:\Soft 3\neo4j-community-3.3.5-windows\neo4j-community-3.3.5\b
>     in\Neo4j-Management.psd1'; Exit (Invoke-Neo4j <<<<  install-service)
> - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorExcep
>     tion
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorExceptio
>     n,Invoke-Neo4j

**What is the cause and how should I resolve it?**

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
java -version
```

on that same commandline.
Java (8) is a requirement for Neo4j so if that command doesn't work that is what is missing.

Regards,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some important info such as OS, 64 or 32bit etc. I can see it's windows so can you check your environment variables and ensure you have either JAVA_HOME set to where your JVM is installed or the path exists in your PATH environment variable?

`Start > Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables`

Also, I can see it's community version, so actually a JVM should come with that edition according to [the installation guide](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/requirements/). Can you try running `bin\neo4j start` to see if that actually starts your database?